# ichiic0 errors on OpenBSD 4.4

Tags: router, openbsd

I have four identical nodes built on Supermicro 1025TC-TB hardware running OpenBSD 4.4. Two of the nodes are routers and two are load balancers. Each set is running in active/passive configuration with failover provided by CARP.

The active router node logs these errors at a rate of about two per hour:
May  5 04:09:30 gw /bsd: ichiic0: abort failed, status 0x0

Occasionally, this one pops up:
May  5 03:59:41 gw /bsd: ichiic0: abort failed, status 0x40

I have not yet found a pattern in when these are logged. ichiic is the Intel SMBus driver. This motherboard also has I/OAT capabilities, but these are not supported under OpenBSD. I am running the latest BIOS.

I suspect that these are logged during particularly high interrupt spikes, but systat is slow enough that I haven't been able to correlate it directly. I have also not been able to replicate this issue manually. The load balancers are not affected.

Any ideas?

Dmesg:

```
OpenBSD 4.4 (GENERIC) #1021: Tue Aug 12 17:16:55 MDT 2008
    deraadt@i386.openbsd.org:/usr/src/sys/arch/i386/compile/GENERIC
cpu0: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5405 @ 2.00GHz ("GenuineIntel" 686-class) 2.01 GHz
cpu0: FPU,V86,DE,PSE,TSC,MSR,PAE,MCE,CX8,APIC,SEP,MTRR,PGE,MCA,CMOV,PAT,PSE36,CFLUSH,DS,ACPI,MMX,FXSR,SSE,SSE2,SS,HTT,TM,SBF,SSE3,MWAIT,DS-CPL,VMX,TM2,CX16,xTPR
real mem  = 3756871680 (3582MB)
avail mem = 3648520192 (3479MB)
mainbus0 at root
bios0 at mainbus0: AT/286+ BIOS, date 08/20/08, BIOS32 rev. 0 @ 0xfdb90, SMBIOS rev. 2.5 @ 0xdff5f000 (39 entries)
bios0: vendor Phoenix Technologies LTD version "1.1" date 08/20/2008
bios0: Supermicro X7DCT
acpi0 at bios0: rev 2
acpi0: tables DSDT FACP APIC MCFG BOOT SPCR ERST HEST BERT EINJ SLIC SSDT SSDT SSDT SSDT SSDT SSDT SSDT SSDT SSDT
acpi0: wakeup devices P0P2(S5) P0P4(S5) USB4(S1) USB5(S1) USB7(S1) ESB2(S1) EXP1(S5) EXP5(S5) EXP6(S5) USB1(S1) USB2(S1) USB3(S1) USB6(S1) ESB1(S1) PCIB(S5) COM1(S5) COM2(S5)
acpitimer0 at acpi0: 3579545 Hz, 24 bits
acpiprt0 at acpi0: bus 1 (P0P2)
acpiprt1 at acpi0: bus 2 (P0P4)
acpiprt2 at acpi0: bus 0 (PCI0)
acpiprt3 at acpi0: bus 3 (EXP1)
acpiprt4 at acpi0: bus 4 (EXP5)
acpiprt5 at acpi0: bus 5 (EXP6)
acpiprt6 at acpi0: bus 6 (PCIB)
acpicpu0 at acpi0
acpibtn0 at acpi0: PWRB
bios0: ROM list: 0xc0000/0xb000
ipmi at mainbus0 not configured
cpu0 at mainbus0
pci0 at mainbus0 bus 0: configuration mode 1 (no bios)
pchb0 at pci0 dev 0 function 0 "Intel 5100 Host" rev 0x90
ppb0 at pci0 dev 2 function 0 "Intel 5100 PCIE" rev 0x90
pci1 at ppb0 bus 1
ppb1 at pci0 dev 4 function 0 "Intel 5100 PCIE" rev 0x90
pci2 at ppb1 bus 2
"Intel I/OAT SCNB" rev 0x90 at pci0 dev 8 function 0 not configured
pchb1 at pci0 dev 16 function 0 "Intel 5100 FSB" rev 0x90
pchb2 at pci0 dev 16 function 1 "Intel 5100 FSB" rev 0x90
pchb3 at pci0 dev 16 function 2 "Intel 5100 FSB" rev 0x90
pchb4 at pci0 dev 17 function 0 "Intel 5100 Reserved" rev 0x90
pchb5 at pci0 dev 19 function 0 "Intel 5100 Reserved" rev 0x90
pchb6 at pci0 dev 21 function 0 "Intel 5100 DDR" rev 0x90
pchb7 at pci0 dev 22 function 0 "Intel 5100 DDR" rev 0x90
uhci0 at pci0 dev 26 function 0 "Intel 82801I USB" rev 0x02: irq 5
ehci0 at pci0 dev 26 function 7 "Intel 82801I USB" rev 0x02: irq 11
usb0 at ehci0: USB revision 2.0
uhub0 at usb0 "Intel EHCI root hub" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 1
ppb2 at pci0 dev 28 function 0 "Intel 82801I PCIE" rev 0x02: irq 10
pci3 at ppb2 bus 3
ppb3 at pci0 dev 28 function 4 "Intel 82801I PCIE" rev 0x02: irq 10
pci4 at ppb3 bus 4
em0 at pci4 dev 0 function 0 "Intel PRO/1000MT (82573E)" rev 0x03: irq 10, address 00:30:48:d4:62:ea
ppb4 at pci0 dev 28 function 5 "Intel 82801I PCIE" rev 0x02: irq 10
pci5 at ppb4 bus 5
em1 at pci5 dev 0 function 0 "Intel PRO/1000MT (82573L)" rev 0x00: irq 10, address 00:30:48:d4:62:eb
uhci1 at pci0 dev 29 function 0 "Intel 82801I USB" rev 0x02: irq 7
uhci2 at pci0 dev 29 function 1 "Intel 82801I USB" rev 0x02: irq 11
uhci3 at pci0 dev 29 function 2 "Intel 82801I USB" rev 0x02: irq 10
ehci1 at pci0 dev 29 function 7 "Intel 82801I USB" rev 0x02: irq 7
usb1 at ehci1: USB revision 2.0
uhub1 at usb1 "Intel EHCI root hub" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 1
ppb5 at pci0 dev 30 function 0 "Intel 82801BA Hub-to-PCI" rev 0x92
pci6 at ppb5 bus 6
vga1 at pci6 dev 1 function 0 "ATI ES1000" rev 0x02
wsdisplay0 at vga1 mux 1: console (80x25, vt100 emulation)
wsdisplay0: screen 1-5 added (80x25, vt100 emulation)
drm at vga1 unsupported
ichpcib0 at pci0 dev 31 function 0 "Intel 82801IR LPC" rev 0x02: PM disabled
pciide0 at pci0 dev 31 function 2 "Intel 82801I SATA" rev 0x02: DMA, channel 0 configured to native-PCI, channel 1 configured to native-PCI
pciide0: using irq 10 for native-PCI interrupt
wd0 at pciide0 channel 0 drive 0: <WDC WD1600BEKT-00F3T0>
wd0: 16-sector PIO, LBA48, 152627MB, 312581808 sectors
wd0(pciide0:0:0): using PIO mode 4, Ultra-DMA mode 5
ichiic0 at pci0 dev 31 function 3 "Intel 82801I SMBus" rev 0x02: irq 10
iic0 at ichiic0
lm1 at iic0 addr 0x2d: W83627HF
wbng0 at iic0 addr 0x2f: w83793g
pciide1 at pci0 dev 31 function 5 "Intel 82801I SATA" rev 0x02: DMA, channel 0 wired to native-PCI, channel 1 wired to native-PCI
pciide1: using irq 11 for native-PCI interrupt
usb2 at uhci0: USB revision 1.0
uhub2 at usb2 "Intel UHCI root hub" rev 1.00/1.00 addr 1
usb3 at uhci1: USB revision 1.0
uhub3 at usb3 "Intel UHCI root hub" rev 1.00/1.00 addr 1
usb4 at uhci2: USB revision 1.0
uhub4 at usb4 "Intel UHCI root hub" rev 1.00/1.00 addr 1
usb5 at uhci3: USB revision 1.0
uhub5 at usb5 "Intel UHCI root hub" rev 1.00/1.00 addr 1
isa0 at ichpcib0
isadma0 at isa0
com0 at isa0 port 0x3f8/8 irq 4: ns16550a, 16 byte fifo
com1 at isa0 port 0x2f8/8 irq 3: ns16550a, 16 byte fifo
pckbc0 at isa0 port 0x60/5
pckbd0 at pckbc0 (kbd slot)
pckbc0: using irq 1 for kbd slot
wskbd0 at pckbd0: console keyboard, using wsdisplay0
pcppi0 at isa0 port 0x61
midi0 at pcppi0: <PC speaker>
spkr0 at pcppi0
wbsio0 at isa0 port 0x2e/2: W83627HF rev 0x41
wbsio0 port 0x290/2 not configured
npx0 at isa0 port 0xf0/16: reported by CPUID; using exception 16
biomask fde5 netmask fde5 ttymask ffff
mtrr: Pentium Pro MTRR support
softraid0 at root
root on wd0a swap on wd0b dump on wd0b
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the latest BIOS? That would be the first thing I would check.

Personally, I have never seeing this error (I run a OBSD 4.4 development box). I researched a bit for you, and I can tell you more than one person has experienced the same problem (even before ODBS 4.4. I am sure you have come across their postings too), but there is no conclusive answer for it. Some attribute it to hyper-threading, some to a failing motherboard.

I will keep this on my list of pending things to discover/learn. Sorry I can't be of further help.

Comment: Forgot to mention that - yes, I'm running the latest BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

That error shows up in function `ichiic_i2c_exec()` of [ichiic.c](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/sys/dev/pci/ichiic.c?rev=1.22;content-type=text%2Fx-cvsweb-markup) and indicates a timeout waiting for the transfer to complete. If it's very rare then I wouldn't worry about it. But I would keep an eye on it in the logs (log checker?). If it starts happening more often I'd suspect the hardware.

Comment: The frequency is given in my original post. I have not been able to determine /what/ transfer is failing across the SMBus, much less why it is failing. Hardware is a fair guess, but it's occurring on two identically configured boxes so I suspect it's more hardware config than actually bad hardware.

Comment: Similar frequency on both boxes? I agree it's probably not hardware then. Do you know if this is polled or interrupt mode?

Comment: Yes, same frequency on both. It is interrupt mode (OpenBSD does not support Polling), but the drivers do support interrupt mitigation.

Comment: Upvoted; I can't see a valid reason for the two downvotes.

Comment: Jan: I've noticed both here and stackoverflow that some people vote down for almost any reason. I.e., the answer is not their favorite, even though it might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to upgrade to snapshot and see if the condition persists?
If it does not solve the issue it can be worth to report it to the developers.

There is a nasty [DoS vulnerability](http://seclists.org/bugtraq/2009/Apr/0122.html) in the version you are using btw.

Comment: Unless you're following errata, like a good SA.

Comment: I'll be upgrading to 4.5 soon, but I won't run -current on a critical production router. We'll see if these disappear in 4.5. And the boxes are following errata, so the DoS is not a worry.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but how do you follow errata if your version reads:

OpenBSD 4.4 (GENERIC) #1021: Tue Aug 12 17:16:55 MDT 2008
 ?

Comment: cstamas> Patch branches are always maintained for two releases previous. A patch was issued for 4.4 as errata item #013 here - http://openbsd.org/errata44.html

Comment: Dan C: yes with a date of "April 11, 2009", but the dmesg output shows 2008 as a compilation date.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.